# How to organize YouTube Playlists?

Tags: google-chrome, youtube

I'm trying to figure out a good way to group my playlists rather than having them just exist as a huge list.  I do a lot with playlists where I create them for different subject areas I'm interested or research that I want to do about a topic, self-training, etc.  Just having a huge list is not very helpful.  I know I could prefix certain ones with a more general idea and then follow it with a more specific one, but the ordering of them on the side panel seem to just be based on the last time you viewed a playlist rather than alphabetical order.
I know about creating sections for your channel, but I don't want these sections visible to my subscribers, they are for my own consumption.

The only way I can think of doing something akin to what I want is to create a set of hierarchical bookmark folders in my browser and then add links to the playlists under the appropriate folder.  Which seems like a lot of work to maintain.

I've looked in YouTube and elsewhere for more organizational tips, looked for Chrome Extensions that might get at what I'm looking for, but so far have come up empty.  It seems kind of strange that this kind of functionality hasn't been a popularly requested feature.  Then again, I've seen a ton of popularly requested features for Chrome and other Google apps that never get implemented because... who knows!